# How to set value of one field as param while using remote link gsp

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am using gsp for the first time and i have a requirement to update a value when a button is clicked. For that I am using remote link.

I have the below textArea with id `update_${test.id}`

```
<g:textArea name="test" id="update_${test.id}" value="${test?.number}" disabled="${readonly ? true : false}" />
```

I need to be able to set the value of the param `required` to be the value inside the textArea.

```
<g:remoteLink action="updateTest" params="{required:\$('#update_${test.id}').val()}" update="updateOnClick" class="btn btn-default"><span class="icon-save"></span></g:remoteLink>
```

This is obviously a wrong approach. Could some one help me with this.

Comment: Are you just trying to send whatever is in the textArea to the updateTest action in your controller?

Comment: @MikeW Yes I am trying to do that. Please let me know how to do it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example uses ajax to pass all the form fields to the controller using serialize, you can pick out which ones you want in your action as we have done below by printing the value of the text area.

We then render some text which updates a div on screen.

Controller

```
class TestStuffController {

    def index(){}

    def myAction() {
        println params.myTextArea
        render 'Updated'
    }
}
```

index.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( '#myButton' ).on( 'click' , function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "${g.createLink( controller: 'testStuff', action: 'myAction')}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $( "form" ).serialize(),
                    success: function ( data ) {
                        $( '#myDiv' ).html( data );
                    },
                    error: function( j, status, eThrown ) { console.log( 'Error ' + eThrown ) }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="myDiv"></div>

            <g:form id="myForm">
                <g:textArea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" />
                <button type="button" name="myButton" id="myButton">Update</button>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a g:link example passing a single name value pair.  To add multiple just add a comma and the second name value pair inside the square brackets.

`<g:link role="button" class="btn btn-success" action="details" params="${['folderNumber' : instance.fileFolderNumber]}" title="Details">Details</g:link>`

Note that g:remoteLink is deprecated I have switched to using JQuery to do Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions. This is what was required. I could reach my solution based on your suggestion.

```
    <g:javascript>
        function updateMethod(testId) {
            $.ajax({url: "${g.createLink( controller: 'testHandler', 
               action: 'testOnChange')}", 
               type: "POST",
               data: {'id': testId},
               success: function ( data ) {
                 $("#rowUpdated").show().delay(2500).fadeOut();
                 $("#updateFailed").hide();
              },
              error: function( j, status, eThrown ) {
                 $("#updateFailed").show().delay(2500).fadeOut();
                 $("#rowUpdated").hide();
                 console.log( 'Error ' + eThrown )
              }
           });
       }
    </g:javascript>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="updateMethod('${test.id}');return false;" class="btn btn-default"><span class="icon-save"></span></a>
```